# cURL with lots of URLs: Unknown error

Tags: php, curl

I'm having a strange problem with cURL that I'm drawing an absolute blank to. It works completely fine locally, but when I upload the files to my webhost and test it over there, it doesn't work at all - it loads for about 2 minutes, and then displays:

> **Server error.**
>
> The website encountered an error while
>   retrieving
>   **http://www.craigwatcher.me/playground/units.php**.
>   It may be down for maintenance or
>   configured incorrectly.

I've checked the error logs but nothing new is being added into there. Basically I'm just iterating through a list of URLs and cURLing each of them. Let me show you the code that I'm working with:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time',0);

require_once('../system/utilities.php'); // This will give us our getLocations()     function, which has been tested to work 100% both locally and online


$categories = array('jjj', 'ggg', 'bbb', 'sss', 'hhh');
$locations = getLocations();
if (!$locations)
    exit;
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);


foreach ($locations as $country => $cities)
{
    $countryCode = getCountryCode($country);

    foreach ($cities as $city) {
        foreach ($categories as $category)
        {
            $url=$city.'.en.craigslist.'.$countryCode.'/'.$category.'/index.rss';
echo $url.'<br/>';
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            $rss = curl_exec($ch);
            if (!$rss)
                echo ' FAILED to load: '.$url.'<br/>';
        }
    }
}

curl_close($ch);
```

I've already tested everything else (eg. the `getLocations()` and `getCountryCode()`, and they prove to work 100% fine both locally and online. What could it **POSSIBLY** be!? I'm pulling my hair out over here, my mind is boggling and I'm completely lost at what could possibly be going wrong.

I've also asked over on PHPFreaks: [post](http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/php-coding-help/error-w-curl-%28lots-of-urls%29/)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a problem with your Server/Host configuration.

Check your [phpinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) to see your curl and PHP.ini settings.

Make sure **allow_url_fopen = on** in your PHP.ini file,

if it is disabled curl probably won't work.

I hope this helps